How to intercept logs to stdout before they are logged in NodeJS?
I have a NodeJS application that uses both debug (external deps use it) and winston (we use it) for logging.
This application now spawns different processes/workers.
Each worker will have a unique WORKER_ID environment variable set.
I want to attach this WORKER_ID to every log, so that I can keep track of which worker is logging what.
The dependencies use their own debug instance, so I can't just do debug.log = ....
How would I intercept all logs to stdout, append my process.env.WORKER_ID, and then log?
Thanks

This could be XY problem, probably this "The dependencies use their own debug instance" needs to be solved instead\
